# The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. - XTRAGRID

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, xtragrid

I am using DEVEXPRESS XTRAGRID in my application having an OledbAdapter that connects to the database and Dataset in my app that binds data using designer of XTRAGRID gridcontrol.

My code no where has any update SQL statements so that I can make the Datetime conversion , the code is as below

```
Public Sub UpdateDatasource1(ByVal grid As GridControl)
        Dim View As ColumnView = grid.FocusedView
        View.CloseEditor()
        If (View.UpdateCurrentRow()) Then
            OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet11, "AexeoTradeBlotter")
        End If
  End Sub
```

For some reason , this statement throws the error "The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column."

I cross checked the xsd file which shows datetime column in system.datetime format. But have no idea why is it throwing this error on update.

Pls help.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, why do you have an old-fashioned OleDbDataAdapter in your code?

Comment: I am sorry , it was a mistake , I have updated the question

Comment: Are your current data include fractional seconds? The error usually occurs because of fractional seconds truncation, since `System.DateTime` has higher precision than standard `datetime` in SQL. Also I can't see the date conversion anywhere as mentioned in the message.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I am using a DevExpress XtraGrid and it does have fractional seconds for that particular column. I want to update that current row with whatever I have selected and edited. The code just selects the row and proceeds for the update.